# Redirected to Outlook calendar in spite of generating a correct outlook calendar item URL

Tags: python, azure, flask, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a Flask dashboard for a user. In one column I have listed their top 10 calendar appointments stored descending by date. I would like the Name of the event to be a link to the event in outlook.com. To Achieve this I used the id property of each event returned by the graph api and used it as a variable in my Jinja template so it looks something like

```
                {% if data['events']  %}
            <ol style="text-decoration:none;">
                {% for event in data['events']['value']%}
                    <li style="margin-bottom: 1em;" > 
                        <b><u><a href="https://outlook.office.com/calendar/item/{{event.id}}">{{ event.subject}}</a></u></b>
                        <p style='margin:0%;'>This is an event organized by <b>{{event.organizer['emailAddress'].name }}</b> that takes
                        place on <b>{{event.start['dateTime'].split('T')[0]}}</b></p>. The location provided is {{event.location['displayName'].strip(' ')}}
                    </li>
```

The Graph call I'm making looks like:

```
# use a query parameter to get the top 10 results from the users calendar, sort by date descending
graph_data['events'] = microsoft.get('me/events?$orderby=end/dateTime%20desc').data
```

The problem is, is that every time I click one of the links I'm redirected to `https://outlook.office.com/calendar/view/week`. Is this normal? Is there a way to get around this? Any help would be much appreciated as I am new to the Graph API and API Development in general.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Comment: Hey sir. So far it hasn't been. For some reason no matter what I do I'm always redirected. my urls are identical to what microsoft's web apps are producing so I'm not sure where to go from here. Have you had any luck with this?

ref https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/ocalendar-oaddevent/link-to-outlook-live-calendar-correct-url/67b96c7d-336a-4ae9-b0fe-3b35ed8e959a

Comment: Did you encode the `event.id` to URL encoded format? When I encode it, I can go to the correct event rather than `https://outlook.office.com/calendar/view/week`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the `event.id` to URL encoded format.

Then you should be able to open the event after signing in.